# How do I strip trailing whitespace before each save in Cloud9?

Tags: cloud9-ide

Cloud9 has a command under Tools called "Strip Trailing Space". I want to automatically run this command before every time I save a file, so I can be sure my files never contain trailing spaces. How is that done?

After frustratedly Googling for quite a while, I can find no documentation on how to achieve stuff like this. They claim Cloud9 is the most hackable IDE in the world though, so it ought to be possible.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well this is embarrassing, but I combed through the preferences again and found the option `On Save, Strip Whitespace` under `Cloud9 -> Preferences -> Code Editor (Ace)`.

Comment: It's now under Cloud9 > Preferences > Code Editor (Ace).

Answer (score 2):

As of July 2015 it is under Cloud9 > "Open your Project Settings" in the top menu bar.

```
"general": {
    "@stripws": false
},
```

Answer (score 0):

`AWS Cloud9` has changed the option `On Save, Strip Whitespace` location to under `Cloud9 -> Preferences -> Project Settings -> Code Editor (Ace)`